# Append list from pandas column to python list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have values in a list in pandas column, for example:

df

```
id       col1
1       [51.97559, 4.12565]
2       [52.97559, 3.12565]
3       [49.97559, 5.12565]
```

But when I append col1 to list I got quote around the first element in each sublist.

```
new_list = []
for val in df['col1'].values:
    new_list.append(val)
```

And I got:

```
[['51.97559', 4.12565]
['52.97559', 3.12565]
['49.97559', 5.12565]]
```

But I need:

```
[[51.97559, 4.12565]
[52.97559, 3.12565]
[49.97559, 5.12565]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast all the elements of the list into `float`

```
new_list = []
for val in df['col1'].values:
    new_list.append(list(map(float, val)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Ditch the loop. Let's vectorize this.

```
new_list = np.array(df['col1'].tolist(), dtype=float).tolist()
```

**Disclaimer**; this won't work if your lists aren't all of the same size. In that case, you'd *need* iteration, but you don't need `map` (that is, if you want performance):

```
new_list = [
    [float(j) for j in i] for i in df['col1'].tolist()
]
```